# Why Unix Join Failed Even Though Corresponding Entries Exist in Two Files

Tags: unix, join

I tried the simple join

```
join query.txt source.tab
```

Based on 1st colum in both files. It's clear that source.tab
contain the query. But why the operation yields no result?

Both of the query and source file is downloadable here:

```
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11482318/query.txt  (2B)

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11482318/source.tab (40KB)
```

Comment: are both files sorted on the first column? If not, they need to be. Do they use the same 'field-separator' (tab, or space)? If not, they need to be ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tha man page for [`join`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?join) says that (as suggested by shelter):

> Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields.

In your case the source.tab file is sorted naturally on the first field (r1.1, r2.1, etc.)  But the sort order required by join would be based on the collating sequence of `sort` (probably r1.1, r10.1, r100.1, r11.1, r12.1, etc.)

If you sort your source.tab file using the `sort` command, then join, it should work.

(Note that - perhaps by luck - the query.txt file has the correct sort order.)

Answer (score 1):

The **join** command will not return results if the file has a header.  This causes **join** to consider the file as unsorted, and thus fails all matches to keys less than that field in the header.

One way to strip the header out is to use `grep -v ",Header2," file1.txt >file2.txt` then join to file2.txt (assuming the file was sorted to begin with).  Another option is to just sort it as it is, allowing the header to remain.  This will work if the header row will not be displayed in the final result.